# ADB driver MK808 installed but ADB is not working

Tags: adb

I wish to setup ADB for MK808

I used Moborobo and it installed ADB driver.

When I connect MK808 I see "ADB Interface - ADB Device" in Device Manager
(instead of unknown device MK808B)

I added `0x2207` to `adb_usb.ini` in \Users\user.android
It is mine device ID and it was one of common IDs in Moborobo .android folder.

If I connect MK808 I see that device in Device Manager if I disconnect it disappear.

I works only when I able USB - Connect to PC and USB Debugging. So they are checked as well as  allow unknown sources.

But `adb` is not working and do not see it.

I use Windows 7 64 bit.

---

PS MK808 shows Bugs debugging icon when connect.

---

PS on Windows XP I did a trick by taking Google USB driver. I added 2207/0006 device ID and installed it. I also got same buggy icon on device when connected.

and new device in ADB device in Device Manager. But adb is not seeing it. 
I added adb_usb.ini to .android folder in my users folder.

---

I rebooted device many times as well.

---

I can connect my phone and adb works fine.

When I say adb is not working it means `adb devices` return 0 list and `logcat` is waiting for device

Answer (score 1):

just use google usb driver in sdk/extra/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf 
you must add three lines in the file

`;MK808B 
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_INSTALL, USB\VID_2207&PID_0006&MI_01
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_INSTALL, USB\VID_2207&PID_0006&REV_0222&MI_01`

Then update the MK808B driver select from disk, use this file sdk/extra/google/usb_driver/android_winusb.inf then select first option is work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu I was able to connect MK808B !!! by adding udev rule like offered [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) and adding device ID to `adb_usb.ini`

If there would be no Windows 7 solutions then I will mark my answer as responded